# Unable to make changes in Drive

Tags: permissions

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I created 2 partitions. First has 50 GB and the other has 250 GB. Everything works in the system drive (create folder, cut/copy) but I am unable to make any changes the the other drive. It opens normally but I am unable to create folder, cut/copy/paste or make any changes.I checked the permissions under 'properties' and it says I am not the owner and all options are greyed out. However when I check system information it says that I am the Administrator. I am attaching two pics for your reference. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> I am not the owner and all options are greyed out.

When you do this you are a USER.

> However when I check system information it says that I am the Administrator.

This is unrelated to your 1st problem: you are BOTH the administrator AND a user.

---

So the answer is: you need to change the permissions of the drive as an administrator for your user to gain access. That those 2 are the same actual person is a coincedence ;)

Command line:

```
sudo chown -r $USER:$USER {/mountpoint}
```

You need to change the {/mountpoint}  to your specific situation. A mountpoint can be an USB and than it could be /media/ubs-stick/. If it is a harddisc it might be mounted in the root system. I have a /discworld in my system.

New user warning: Before issueing the command have someone confirm you are doing it correctly. You will mess up your file if you put "/" or "/etc/" as a mountpoint ;)

Comment: I am new to Ubuntu. Can you please explain what mountpoint i have to enter

Comment: That is the directory name of that drive (your probably gave it a name during formatting/installation)

Comment: How can I find the mountpoint

Comment: any option I can use to find the mountpoint name?

Comment: "location" in the properties page of that disc.

Comment: I am sorry but I am getting an error:

Comment: arijit@arijit-desktop:~$ sudo chown -r $USER:$USER {/media/arijit} 
[sudo] password for arijit: 
chown: invalid option -- 'r'
Try 'chown --help' for more information.
arijit@arijit-desktop:~$